# ScandiPWA + Session Issue with Safari

Tags: magento2, pwa, authorize, iphone

I have problem with customer session with ScandiPWA on Safari Browser (Desktop + iPhone)
After log into account in Safari Browser i get redirect to My Account. I get a immediately exception that The current customer isn't authorized. Problem occurre only in this specific browser. On chrome, firefox etc. everythink is ok. Do you meet with this problem? Logs are almost empty and didn't come with any path to check to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. It's test page and we have basic auth. When I turned off cross-site tracking problem was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

*Clear cache and cookies: Sometimes, cached data and cookies stored in the browser can cause issues with website sessions. Try clearing your browser's cache and cookies and then attempt to log in again.

Disable browser extensions: Browser extensions can interfere with website sessions. Try disabling any browser extensions you have installed and then attempt to log in again.

Update Safari browser: Make sure that you have the latest version of the Safari browser installed on your device. An outdated browser can cause compatibility issues with certain websites.
Check your server logs: If you have access to your server logs, you can check them for any error messages or clues that may point to the issue.*